# In SSIS, Hoew to assign a value to the variable?

Tags: ssis

I have SQL Query in that have mentioned like `@Result`.
Now i want to assign the value of `@Result` to the declared variable in `Execute SQL task` of DFT. Could you please assist me?

here is the query:

```
DECLARE @Result SMALLINT 
DECLARE @VALUE  SMALLINT

BEGIN 
SET @VALUE = (SELECT Value 
              from dbo.LDMStockIntegrityCheck 
              where InterfaceName =  'I0180'
              and FileName = 'PIZ.ED.NBFS001.PICSHT.DATA.LDM')
SET @Result = 0;

IF (@VALUE = 1)
BEGIN 
Select @Result = count(*) from dbo.LDMIntegrityErrorLog 
where InterfaceName = 'I0180' and FileName = 'PIZ.ED.NBFS001.PICSHT.DATA.LDM'
and  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 120);
END 

END
```

Comment: Can you show your query what your actually doing becuase in `Execute SQL Task` mapping can done by specifying `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to `Output` the value of `count` from the query `count(*) from dbo.LDMIntegrityErrorLog` then i don't see the importance of the variable `@Result`

```
DECLARE @VALUE  SMALLINT

BEGIN 
SET @VALUE = (SELECT Value 
              from dbo.LDMStockIntegrityCheck 
              where InterfaceName =  'I0180'
              and FileName = 'PIZ.ED.NBFS001.PICSHT.DATA.LDM')

IF (@VALUE = 1)
BEGIN 
Select count(*) as Result from dbo.LDMIntegrityErrorLog 
where InterfaceName = 'I0180' and FileName = 'PIZ.ED.NBFS001.PICSHT.DATA.LDM'
and  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 120);
END 
ELSE
SELECT NULL AS Result
END
```

Remove the variable `@Result` in the query

Now create a variable `TaskResult` of data type `int` .Map this variable to the `result` from the above query.

[image]

Comment: thanks For your response.. But i want to know How to map this variable to the result from the above query?  Iam not sure how to map this variable to the result from the above query?

Comment: This is wat i have shown in the above `image`.In the `General` tab of Execute sql task change `Resultset` to `Single Row` and the in the `Result Set` tab map the variable

Comment: In Result Set I have given like Result Name = @Result and Variable Name as User::Result

Comment: But of No luck Praveen!! :(

Comment: I think you are getting confused . You don't have `Name` variable defined in your query.Do you want the result from your sql query to be saved in `some variable` ?

Comment: Then the complete answer is described in my solution above . Just write the `sql query` which i have written.Create a new variable `TaskResult` .Set `ResultSet` to `Single Row` and in the `Result Set` tab map the variables as shown above . If you are still not able to do it then check this article http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx

Comment: small Clarification!!! If The Condition is true for SQL Query Result but flow got stucked in Esecute SQL Task means , can we assume like Environmental issue or design problem?

Comment: What do u mean by 'Flow Got stucked' ? Does the `Execute SQL Task` throw `error` ? Then kindly check `Execution result` to find out what caused the error

Comment: It doesn't threw any error. but flow will not goto next step even thogh Precedence Constraint Condition is true!!!

Comment: Try to put `breakpoints` for `Pre` and `Post Execute` events and see the value for the variables

Comment: Yeah i have done that. I have Assigned the Precedence Constraint as Failure to completion then the flow is going as expected. Do we have any constraints for Failure Precedence Constraints?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do u want your `tasks` to stop executing after `execute sql task` or want to execute even after `failure` .

Comment: Thanks Load Praveen For your continuous help. Iam really very much satisfied with your responses.

Comment: Hi praveen,Could you please help me in this scenario: I have a scenario, like: One ErrorLog table is there, If is there any records in this table for current date(GETDATE()) I want to hold these records in anothr temporary table and need to delete the current records in this table after exection of Stored Procedure. I would like to know about the logic to implement this?

Comment: As per your query which was given yesterday, if value is one that will count the records in ErrorLogTable for an Stored procedure execution. but now If i want to re run the SP execution those records need to be cleared in Error Log table and should placed in another temporary table. then only my package will do as expected. i want to imlpent that logic as well

Comment: @DharanKumarA:It will be better if you post it as a seperate question so that others can also help u and also it won't clutter the answer provided above.

Comment: Yeah i have posted seperately. but as i have discussed about his to you yesterday so i posted to you seperately

Comment: That's fine .In your new question just link this page (if there is any relation to this question) so that others can understand it.